# PHP PDO Login... Echo email after login error fail

Tags: php

I have a login page and a dashboard page where the user will land after login (note: the dashboard page is in another folder) ....

**login.php**

```
    <?php
include 'dbcon.php';
if(isset($_POST['sdsubmit'])){
    $sdemail=$_POST['sdemail'];
    $sdpassword=$_POST['sdpassword'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM students WHERE email = ? && password= ?";
    $query=$db->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute(array($sdemail, $sdpassword));
    $row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
    if($row > 0){
        session_start();
        $sdemail=$_SESSION['sdemail'];
        header("Location: student/index.php");
        exit();
    }
    else{
        echo "<script>alert('Sorry, email or password is incorrect. Please try again');
</script>";
    }
}
```

**form(same page in the login.php)**

```
    <form id="login-form1" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>" method="post" role="form" style="display: block;">
        <div class="form-group">
                 <input type="email" name="sdemail" id="sdemail" required="required" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" value="">
        </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="password" name="sdpassword" id="sdpassword" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                <input type="submit" name="sdsubmit" id="login-submit" tabindex="4" class="form-control btn btn-login" value="Login">
        </div>
    </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

**dashboard(index.php)**

```
<?php
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['sdemail'];
```

**dbcon.php(database connectivity)**

```
<?php
$errmsg_arr = array();
$errflag = false;
try{
    $db=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=internshala', 'root', '');
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo "Sorry, cannot connect to database";
}
```

**error**

> Notice: Undefined index: sdemail in C:\xampp\htdocs\Internshala\student\index.php on line 3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)

Comment: You never set `$_SESSION['sdemail']` anywhere in this code.

Comment: Hello I have set $_SESSION['sdemail']=$sdemail as:  `if($row > 0){
        session_start();
        $sdemail=$_SESSION['sdemail'];
        header("Location: student/index.php");
        exit();
    }`

Comment: please check my login.php

Comment: `$sdemail=$_SESSION['sdemail'];` still doesn't *set* the session, it tries to use it.

Comment: How i set it please help me im new in php

Comment: You have it in the reverse order.. This is quite basic, you should perhaps read the [**manual on variables (basic)**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php).

Comment: $_SESSION['sdemail'] = $sdemail; currently it is the wrong way around

Comment: Thanks bro it works

Answer (score 0):

```
session_start();
$sdemail=$_SESSION['sdemail']; // refer 1
$_SESSION['sdemail'] = $sdemail; // just replace the above line with this
In dashboard.php
if(isset($_SESSION['sdemail']))
{ echo $sdemail; }// replace this
```

1. here you are assigning the value to $sdemail from session($_SESSION['sdemail'])